# Conditional sub menus in _layout.cshml

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am having a play with ASP.NET MVC 5 having used ASP.NET but not MVC before.

I have an entity framework powered set of controllers which return pages with that fall into two broad categories: *Devices* (`DeviceUsage`, `DeviceErrors`, etc.) and *Stores* (`Stores`, `StoreInstallations`, etc.)

I have a `_layout.cshml` page which lays out a page header which contains the major navigational areas of the website (Stores and Devices).  What I would like is the second layer of navigation that shows only the pages within that category, that is, when viewing any of `DeviceUsage`, `DeviceErrors` etc, only these options appear in the sub menu.

What is the easiest/best/standard way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Create a section so you can add dynamic content there. You may want to use other razor functions like @Html.Action or @Html.RenderAction.
[Here is a tutorial for sections](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/3d39b4/Asp-Net-mvc-4-layout-and-section-in-razor/) if you need.

Comment: So I could use a `@RenderSection()` in the `layout.cshml` and define the section in each view.  Is there a way to share the code between different views though? so `DeviceUasge.cshtml` and `DeviceErrors.cshtml` have the same, but `Stores.cshtml` and `StoreInstallations.cshtml` have another different one?

Comment: I don't know what structure your application has but what you can do is define `@RenderSection("SubMenu", required: false)` in your `layout.cshtml`. Then in `DeviceUsage.cshtml` and `DeviceErrors.cshtml` use a PartialView that gets same view like `@section SubMenu{@Html.PartialView("DeviceSubMenu")}` function. And in store views you can use `@section SubMenu{@Html.PartialView(StoreSubMenu")}`